# How to properly use WebAudio and Timer in Dart

Tags: dart

I want to create a random sound sequencer, just for learning more about WebAudio and Dart.

My idea is to load some sound examples and play them in random order endlessly.

For that, I've loaded all the files, decoded them in a arraybuffer and put them to play with the following function:

```
void startAudio()
{
   int index=random.nextInt(buffers.length);
   print("Audio played [${index}].");
   source.buffer=buffers[index];
   source.connect(context.destination, 0, 0);
   source.start(0);
   Timer timer=new Timer(100, this.proceed);
}

void proceed(Timer timer)
{
   this.startAudio();
}
```

The problem is that after some time, the sounds stop playing.

What is going wrong?

Is it the best way to do what I'm trying to do?

If someone wants to test my code, here is the link:
http://cg.usr.sh/Dart/WebAudioTest/WebAudioTest.html

Answer (score 2):

After randomly changing things, I got it working as I was expecting.

```
 import 'dart:html';
 import 'dart:math';
 import 'dart:async';

 class AudioMaker
 {
   List<String> urls;

   AudioContext context;
   List<AudioBuffer> buffers;

   Random random;

   AudioMaker()
   {
     this.urls=new List<String>();
     this.context=new AudioContext();
     this.buffers=new List<AudioBuffer>();
     this.random=new Random(0);
   }

   void checkAndStart()
   {
     if(buffers.length == urls.length)
     {
       Timer timer=new Timer.repeating(500, this.startAudio);
     }
   }

   void startAudio(Timer timer)
   {
     int index=random.nextInt(this.buffers.length);
     print("Audio played [${index}].");
     AudioBufferSourceNode source=context.createBufferSource();
     source.buffer=this.buffers[index];
     source.connect(context.destination, 0, 0);
     source.start(0);
   }

   void _decodeAudio(url)
   {
     HttpRequest hr=new HttpRequest.get(url, (req){
       this.context.decodeAudioData(req.response, (audio_buff)
           {
             print("${url} decoded.");
             this.buffers.add(audio_buff);
             checkAndStart();
           }, (evt)
           {
             print("Error");
           });
     });
     hr.responseType="arraybuffer";
   }

   void loadAndStart()
   {
     for(String url in this.urls)
     {
       this._decodeAudio(url);
     }
   }
 }

 main()
 {
   AudioMaker audioMaker=new AudioMaker();
   audioMaker.urls.add("bark.ogg");
   audioMaker.urls.add("drip.ogg");
   audioMaker.urls.add("glass.ogg");
   audioMaker.urls.add("sonar.ogg");
   audioMaker.loadAndStart();
 }
```